# Фигурная стрелка с плавным переходом CSS

Tags: css, svg

Необходимо реализовать стрелку у сообщения такого рода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она имеет небольшие внутренние изгибы, в инете ничего не смог найти, везде обычные треугольники.

Я понимаю что легко можно добавить изображение, но мне хотелось бы разобраться как это сделать с помощью чистого css и возможно ли это вообще.

Comment: Используй svg .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Рекомендую использовать `SVG`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 25px;
}

.angle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: -43px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <div class="angle">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100" height="100">
      <path fill="dodgerblue" d="m 25,56 c 0,0 19,-5 18,-11 l 0,24 c 0,0 0,-3 -18,-12 z"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima eaque saepe porro ex laudantium debitis praesentium beatae dolores maiores voluptates, qui animi vero non cum quisquam adipisci placeat iste provident?
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Круто получилось. Спасибо.